# Is there a grep-like command that can understand vim regex syntax?

Tags: linux, grep

ack, ag, grep, pgrep, ripgrep, ugrep are binary filter commands that understand various regex syntax flavors. Is there a binary filter command that can also understand vim regex syntax flavor? I'm so used to type searches the vim way that I would find such a filter useful.

I googled for "reuse vim regex engine" and "use vim regex engine in another program" but no hit was relevant to my question.

Comment: Within Vim you can use `:vimgrep` it is slower than `ack` or `ripgrep` but support the Vim syntax.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, thank you. Yes, I am aware that `:vimgrep` is an actual command _within_ vim. However, my question concerns external commands that understand vim regex syntax flavor, either because they embed vim's regex engine or because they duplicate its syntax.

Comment: I had that understanding but maybe your question could be more explicit about it.

Comment: Fair point. What could be more explicit than the current "is there a _binary filter command_"? Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt it exist. If I would need such tool I would create a Vim function that use grep and output the content of the Quicklist into the standard output and call Vim with the appropriate `--cmd` argument.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably use some extra work, but I have the following (bash) function:

```
vgrep () {
  local pattern="${1////\\/}"
  shift
  for f; do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
      ex -N -i NONE -n -- "$f" <<< "argdo global/$pattern/print" | sed "s/^/${f////\\/}:/"
    fi
  done
}
```

This takes a pattern and a list of files and prints the matches in each file to standard out, prefixed by `<filename>:`. Each file is given to `ex` with a command to print the matches `:global/pattern/print`.

The hackery to escape slashes is not ideal, and you may find that there are inputs that break the script. Indeed, the same code doesn't work as expected in Zsh.

---

In retrospect, I'm not sure why `argdo` is there either. Perhaps it can be removed (I suspect the original version didn't have the file prefixing, so could pass all the arguments at once).

Comment: Extra work I don't know, but it could certainly use some explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the zsh function, it's a start. `vgrep 'a\{1\}' file` prints `sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to 's'` (zsh 5.8.1 linux). If I change both `////` to `//` this error goes away, but the pattern becomes `a{1}` and doesn't match as intended.

Comment: @stepse hm, looks like the original was written for bash, in which the expansion works as intended. For zsh, I'll have to fix it.

Comment: Yes, bash seems to work.

Comment: I just realized that vgrep can only process files, so it won't work as a filter, that is, after a `|`   pipe. I am also looking for a filter.